# String of directory to tree view

Tags: php, html

How to turn this string into an tree view or directory listing (by using ul, li html)

Folder A/
Folder A/Folder B/
Folder A/Folder B/Folder C/
Folder A/Folder B/Folder C/Readme.docx
Folder A/Folder B/Folder D/
Folder A/Folder B/Folder D/File1.exe
Folder A/Folder B/Folder D/File2.exe
Folder A/Folder B/Folder F/
Folder A/Folder B/Folder F/File3.exe
Folder A/Folder B/Folder F/File4.exe
Folder G/

Expected output

- Folder A

  - Folder B

    - Folder C

      - Readme.docx
    - Folder D

      - File1.exe
      - File2.exe
    - Folder F

      - File3.exe
      - File4.exe
- Folder G

I know that there's explode() and looping in php but i don't know the implementation, if i explode it by "/" and then we get the last index to be the filename and then how to group all of them by folder?

Comment: Then minimum you could do is give a wanted output/result.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i just add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there ! If you know of explode and looping, you just need to add [PHP_EOL](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/reserved.constants.php) (hoping you are at least on PHP 5.0.2*) to the equation. Aaaand be a little good at logic games ^^

```
$text='Folder A/
Folder A/Folder B/
Folder A/Folder B/Folder C/
Folder A/Folder B/Folder C/Readme.docx
Folder A/Folder B/Folder D/
Folder A/Folder B/Folder D/File1.exe
Folder A/Folder B/Folder D/File2.exe
Folder A/Folder B/Folder F/
Folder A/Folder B/Folder F/File3.exe
Folder A/Folder B/Folder F/File4.exe
Folder G/';

$lines=explode(PHP_EOL,$text);
$actual_folder=array();
foreach($lines as $line){
  $path_parts=explode('/',$line);
  foreach($path_parts as $i=>$part){
    if(isset($actual_folder[$i]) AND $actual_folder[$i]==$part)continue;
    while($i<count($actual_folder) and count($actual_folder)!=0){
      echo '</ul>';
      array_pop($actual_folder);
    }
    if($part!=''){
      if(!isset($actual_folder[$i]))echo '<ul>';
      echo '<li>'.$part.'</li>';
      $actual_folder[$i]=$part;
    }
  }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

*else it depends on your server, it may be \n or \r\n